# How to pass a JPA entity to an Asynchronous EJB method

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb

While processing a request, I would like to 'kick off' separate task in a separate transaction based on the data received and stored in the database.
The main advantage is that I can return the result to my request before all additional processing is done, also if additional processing fails, this will not affect the original processing of the request (as they are in different transactions). This additional processing might require adding extra information to the data.

I have the following setup in mind. Where using `@Asynchronous` the additional task is created.

```
@Stateless
public class Bean1
{
    @EJB 
    Bean2 bean2;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public MyResult doSomething(MyInput input) {
        MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
        // Fill data based on input
        entityManager.persist(myEntity);

        bean2.asyncActOnData(myEntity);
        // Perhaps do some more work and return result
    }
}

@Stateless
public class Bean2
{
    @Asynchronous // This causes a new transaction to happen
    public void asyncActOnData(MyInput input){
         // Act upon data and store result in DB
    }
}
```

This seems like a clean way, however this causes JPA Entity to become detached, possibly during processing in `Bean2`.

Currently I don't plan on changing the data after the persist call (and asnyc), but as the application grows I feel it would be safer to allow this to avoid mistakes.

What is the correct way to kick off the separate asynchronous task based on the persisted data?

I am using: Java EE 6 with Eclipselink 2.5.2 for JPA.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue to make use of the detached instance provided that:

1. You're not planning to perform further persistence operations;
2. All associated entities (if any) were available when `asyncActOnData` was invoked.

However, if you need to perform further persistence operations you can do the following:

```
@Stateless
public class Bean1
{
    @EJB 
    Bean2 bean2;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public MyResult doSomething(MyInput input) {
        MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
        // Fill data based on input
        entityManager.persist(myEntity);

        // Flush the persistence context and detach the entity
        // An entity is not permitted to be in more than one
        // persistence context at a time. This should prevent
        // a race condition with the merge in bean2.
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.detach(myEntity);
        Future<Result> futureResult = bean2.asyncActOnData(myEntity);

        // Perhaps do some more work and return result
        ....

        return futureResult.get();
    }
}

@Stateless
public class Bean2 {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Asynchronous
    public Future<Result> asyncActOnData(MyInput input) {
         // this will ensure that the database still matches input
         // and add input into the persistence context
         input = entityManager.merge(input);
         ...
         return new javax.ejb.AsyncResult<Result>(result);
    }

}
```

You will find it useful to read §3.2 of the "Java™ Persistence API, Version 2.1" specification.

Comment: Do you mean to do both merge and refresh? Just refresh is not allowed on a detached object it seems (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Persisting#Refresh). Doing a merge and then a refresh might actually reset this to the database state. Although if the refresh happens before the commit in Bean1 it would probably fail?

Comment: It looks like I  mis-read the spec. Sorry about that as I had intended either/or. It seems `merge` is the only way to go.

Comment: Note that I think you need to deliberately detach the entity before invoking `asyncActOnData`